# XMLHttpRequest ERROR in QML Blackberry 10

Tags: json, blackberry-10

I'm trying to get movie data for BlackBerry 10 apps.
I don't know where I'm making a mistake.
Please, can you help me?
Thank you all.

```
import bb.cascades 1.4

Page {

    onCreationCompleted: {
        sendRequest();
    }

    function sendRequest() {
        var data = "{}";

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.withCredentials = true;

        xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
                if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
                    console.log(this.responseText);
                }
        });

        xhr.open("GET", "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?include_adult=false&page=1&query=hulk&language=en-US&api_key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE");

        xhr.send(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `onreadystatechange` EventHandler.
Also, you don't need to pass data when making a `GET` request.
I have removed the `withCredentials` line as it isn't needed in this example.

You can learn more on `XMLHttpRequest` here : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

```
onCreationCompleted: {
    sendRequest();
}

function sendRequest() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            var results = json.results;
            var count = results.length;

            console.log("There are " + count + " results :");
            json.results.forEach((value, index) => 
            {
              console.log(index + " - " + value.title);
            });
        }
    };

    xhr.open("GET", "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?include_adult=false&page=1&query=hulk&language=en-US&api_key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE");
    xhr.send();
}
```

Here's an example of using `XMLHttpRequest` I've made a long time ago : 
https://github.com/RodgerLeblanc/Markup/blob/master/assets/main.qml

Comment: Hello, great, thank you very much for your answer.

I did it with your example.

So, another question, how to use this data?
I just need to pick some parts from JSON, not all.

Thank you in advance for your answer and help.

Comment: I've modified my answer to give an example of how to read the json string. You can copy/paste the json string into an online json editor to inspect it and understand how the json is represented. `JSON.parse` allows to get an object from the returned string, from there I get the `results` property value, which is an array. I then print to console the `title` property value for each element. Don't forget to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to mark the post as answered. If you have other questions, don't post it in comments, start a new thread instead.